# Access Standalone Spark Master behind VPC on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, amazon-vpc, ambari

I have an Ambari Cluster with Spark History Server and I have also started a standalone Spark Master on the Master Node. The whole setup is on Amazon EC2 cluster behind VPC.

i.e I have two IPs public and private.

Eg: Public IP: 10.1.1.1  Private IP: 110.123.12.1

Below is the /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1    localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 
::1          localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

10.1.1.1     hadoopmaster
110.123.12.1 hadoopmaster
```

Now, I cannot start the Spark Standalone master with the public IP. So, I started it with the private IP. So I can connect to the master using the spark shell locally as below:

```
spark-shell --master spark://110.123.12.1:7071
```

This works fine.

But, when I try to connect **remotely from a different box** as below, it fails:

```
spark-shell --master spark://10.1.1.1:7071
```

Anybody has a solution ??

Comment: You found a solution? Do not use `/etc/hosts`. `110.123.12.1` is a public IP, you should try to connect to `110.123.12.1` instead of `10.1.1.1`

Comment: @helloV I tried the public IP first, but that didn't work.